# Eclipse Oxygen no driver definition for MySql

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I tried to create new Database Connection but "Specify a driver template and definition name" doesn't have any option for MySql.
[image]

I tried to go to Preference->Driver Definition. Choose MySql but it doesn't have any option again. Could you please help my with this.
[image]

Comment: you tried to add right?

Comment: no, what I should do to add rights?

Answer (score 2):

i had this problem too,
you just have to press Add, then on name and type expand the window by pulling it further down so you can view the table on first picture

here a picture of what i mean

[eclipse driver definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCHRm.jpg)